# How to do Object–Relational mapping in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I'm currently tring to port an application using hibernate to ABAP.

So short version is: I've (at least) two tables, let's say `Entity(entity_id, ...)` and `SubEntity(sub_entity_id, entity_id)`.

Now in ABAP OO I'm representing these entities as classes, like `zcl_app_entity`. Now I'm wondering how I could use ABAP to persist these entities and relationships.

I've use-cases like:

- Lock entity, and then add subentity
- Get all subEntities and send them via http as json

In Java with JPA I'd do something like

```
Entity entity = userRepository.findById(entityId);
entity.lock(); // granted, this mechanism would on DB Level here while ABAP needs ABAP Locks
entity.getSubEntities.add(address);
```

There's a session with UnitOfWork automatically with the repository call. But as far as I'm aware ABAP doesn't offer a Repository pattern which automatically transforms classes to managed entities.

I could of course add `INSERT` etc directly into the add calls, or create a `load` / `persist` method on every class. But then I lose the testability.

I could create `Repositories` myself, passing in the objects. But then my Objects are repository aware itself (addAddress would call the repository).

Another way would be in the service class to call the repository, and then pass that object to the add method after it's persisted. Quite error prone.

Also lazy loading of e.g. xstrings (like 50MB) would be great, this won't work when the object has no access to the repository / sql interface to load on demand though.

I'd be super suprised if there isn't something like this (JPA/Hibernate), since these are common patterns.

`IEntityRepository, ISubEntitiyRepository, IMyService (calls repo interfaces)`

All calls make objects managed, maybe with OneToMany etc relationships, rollbacks, lazy load.

Weirdly I found the most ABAP way to have some logic in classes (e.g. the Entity->lock( ), entity->add_subentity( xyz ) but then just use an SQL persistency interface to get all data and return some structures. There wouldn't really be OO relationships. At most a class would be used as a short time driver of a struct. But when I'd say update all sub_entities it would be more like `data_provider->get_sub_entity( entity_id )` which returns an internal table. And then the requestor has to persist it again if required data_provider->update_sub_entity_status( entity_id, 'R' )

So how do I use Object–Relational mapping in ABAP, e.g. when I want to update the status of all sub_entities of entitiy X to 'DONE' while keeping it testable?

Comment: Perhaps the [Business Object Processing Framework](https://community.sap.com/topics/abap/bopf) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps [Restful Application Programming](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenarap_glosry.htm) (Behaviors, CDS, etc.) and [Core Data Services](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abencds.htm)?

Comment: @SandraRossi Seems to be the only way besides BOPF. Though modeling everything that a service would do as a direct action on entities is a bit limited (kind of like putting the service logic into the model). Behavior Pools not having constructors to mock repositories is also a bit annoying. So when accessing other entities with EML all I can do is use the EML mocking. Testdoubles are out of the picture then :(

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, will also look into that (RAP seems to be the new thing on top of it itself). Sadly it's an old complicated framework, but I'll check it out! Thanks

Comment: what is your scenario for this task? you call BOPF complicated but what you are inventing seems much more error-prone and complicated, than learning BOPF

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the basic ABAP persistence service.

In se24 if you create a class, you can mark it as "persistent".
[image: Define a persistent class]

Eg SFLIGHT.

[image: Generate code, see the settings]

[image: Assign a structure to use]
[https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/18/abap-persistent-object-services-demystified/#:~:text=The%20Persistence%20Object%20Services%20can,again%20when%20you%20need%20them](https://blogs.sap.com/2012/04/18/abap-persistent-object-services-demystified/#:%7E:text=The%20Persistence%20Object%20Services%20can,again%20when%20you%20need%20them).

There is an generated example on every system  `CL_SPFLI_PERSISTENT`

If you have used ORMs in other languages like c# , this will be a very disappointing experience.

This toolset began around 20 yrs ago, but offers a questionable return on invest if you ask me.

Apart from the fact the approach doesnt conform to traditional OO principals.

[image: Method with 20 Importing params rather than an object ????]

When this first came out SAP already had 3GL code updating traditional
tables.  Most developers even SAP internal, had no clear idea how to implement an ABAP OO model.

90% of the code SAP delivered didnt use this type of model. So there where no good examples to base your own work on.
Unfortunately it never took off and was never extended to have the functionality expected in a true ORM persistence tool.

I dont recall seeing anything inside the toolset that manages things like cascade delete. Nor A proper class relationship model?
**Please correct me if I missed that.**

If you ask me, sap generated a class with GET and SET methods and a PERSIST method and that was where it stopped.

Actually using Classes not DDIC structures as the model and implementing things like cascade delete look outstanding.

If you google SAP and ORM you will see a Javascript tool using Hibernate and HANA as the DB. Not an ABAP based tool.
or you will see ORM meaning Operational Risk Mgt.
That pretty much says it all.  The ABAP layer has a toy Class generator but no true ORM tool like entity framework on .net.